# what for we have to write at the end of the function "return"? in c++

Tags: c++, return

Can someone exlain me what is that "return" at the end of the function and why we have to write at the end of the main function return 0.e.g

```
int main()
 {
  .....
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You are requesting something from the function right ? So you do need to have a `return`. If you don't expect anything from the function, Just declare it as `void main() { .... //no need to have return call}`

Comment: @sh4nx0r: no, *that is not valid*. `main` must have an `int` return type. And in any case, `main` is special in that you don't really need to return anything from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *don't* have to write `return` at the end of `main` in C++; a return value of `0` is implicit. (This is different in C, where you do have to return a value.)

What this does is return a value to the program's environment, so that it can be known whether the program succeeded (zero) or encountered some error (non-zero). Other programs, including shell scripts/batch files can use this information to make decisions, e.g. they can stop early when an error is encountered in a program they run.

Answer (score 0):

All CPUs that support function calls have an instruction like `RET`, to explicitly return from inside the called function, back to the code that called the function. The memory address of the code to return to after the function call has already been saved in a "well know place" (e.g. the stack). The `RET` instruction will retrieve that memory address and point the CPU at the correct location, in order to resume executing at the code that comes after the original function call.

In c++, some functions are declared to "return" specific values (like the function main above), while other functions never return any values (those declared as having a return type of void). Its your choice how you declare the functions that you write. If the function return type is void, you would *not* need an explicit return statement in your code, *unless* you were returning prematurely, like from inside an if, else or loop. For example:

```
void foo(int x) {
    if (x == 0)
        return; // premature return to caller

    int b = x*2;
    // do some more stuff
    // and now no need to say return, its done implicitly because we are at function end
}
```

However when your function is declared as having a non-void return type (for example int), then you should have an explicit return statement in the function, even if you are *not* returning prematurely.

```
int bar(int y) {        
    return y*7;
}
```

because the caller is expecting it and may assign the return value to a variable like this:

```
int z = bar(4);
```